# PYTHON Program Run(Executed) when keyboard input is press

Tags: python, keyboard

Hello I have to a simple python project using Slushengine motor driver to run several motor. I already make example program (as shown as below code), but now I want the motor run when I press key from keyboard(input) for example ENTER key. Then I want the program stop when I press another key.

```
from inputs import get_key
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Slush
import math
import time

from time import sleep

b = Slush.sBoard()
m = [Slush.Motor(0), Slush.Motor(1), Slush.Motor(2), Slush.Motor(3)]

m[0].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[1].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[2].setMaxSpeed(250)
m[3].setMaxSpeed(150)

m[0].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[1].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)
m[2].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[3].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 100)
pwm.start(0)
GPIO.output(18, True)

pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(1)
sleep(0.5)
m[1].goTo(750)
time.sleep(3)
m[0].goTo(750)
time.sleep(3)
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(99)
sleep(1)
```

I need to execute this code when keypress detected.

```
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(1)
sleep(0.5)
m[1].goTo(750)
time.sleep(3)
m[0].goTo(750)
time.sleep(3)
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(99)
sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't it already shown in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/inputs/)?

```
from inputs import get_key

def key_input():
    while 1:
        events = get_key()
        for event in events:
            print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key_input()
```

Comment: You should edit your own code instead of posting a new one as an answer. Anyway, looks fine to me. You can always try by `print ("YES")` and see if it records your enter key

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?? sorry im not clear yet

```
from inputs import get_key
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Slush
import math
import time

from time import sleep

b = Slush.sBoard()
m = [Slush.Motor(0), Slush.Motor(1), Slush.Motor(2), Slush.Motor(3)]

m[0].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[1].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[2].setMaxSpeed(250)
m[3].setMaxSpeed(150)

m[0].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[1].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)
m[2].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[3].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 100)
pwm.start(0)
GPIO.output(18, 1)

while 1:
    events = get_key()
    for event in events:

        if event.code == 'KEY_ENTER':
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(1)
            time.sleep(1)
            m[1].goTo(750)
            time.sleep(3)
            m[0].goTo(750)
            time.sleep(3)
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(99)
            time.sleep(1)
```